# How to run package file(.pkg) from install4j

Tags: installation, install4j

I'm a newbie to install4j. I am creating an installer for Mac where it will trigger installation of other dependent software. I am able trigger it in case of .dmg files using option "Run executable or batch file". But in case of package files (.pkg) its failing and giving error.
How can I trigger the installation on such package files from install4j?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72226/installing-pkg-with-terminal/72227

Comment: Thanks @IngoKegel . I tried installation command in terminal and it works fine. Now I added action 'Run executable..' where executable is script.sh file and working directory as '.' with wait for termination on. But this script execution fails with error msg that I've set under Error Handling. Not sure what must be wrong. Below is script  " #! bin / bin/bash
sudo installer -pkg myPackage.pkg -target / "
Here package file is under Files -> Installation directory.

Comment: In the action, you can configure that stderr and stdout output are redirected to the log file to check what goes wrong